# Match-3 should pieces store their location in the matrix?

Tags: unity, algorithm, matrix

I'm making a match-3 game. I have a TileManager script which stores all the tiles in a matrix, it's a singleton and it handles tile swapping and basicly everything regarding the management of tiles.

I have a variable called selectedTile. I have a method called SwapSelected which swaps the currently selected tile with the one you just clicked on. As pieces don't know their location in the matrix I can only loop through the whole thing to find them but it feels extremly stupid I just feel like there's gotta be a better way. If pieces stored their location and I kept that updated all the time that'd feel stupid too.

What could I do to make this method work nicer and more optimalized? Is there a way or there is no problem with how I do it?

```
    public void SwapSelected(Tile tileToSwap)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = selectedTile.transform.position;
        selectedTile.transform.position = tileToSwap.transform.position;
        tileToSwap.transform.position = tempPos;

        Vector2Int tileToSwapPosition = new Vector2Int(-1, -1);
        Vector2Int selectedTilePosition = new Vector2Int(-1, -1);

        //OPTIMALIZE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        for (int x = 0; x < _tileMap.GetLength(0); x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < _tileMap.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (_tileMap[x, y] == tileToSwap)
                {
                    tileToSwapPosition = new Vector2Int(x, y);
                }
                if (_tileMap[x, y] == selectedTile)
                {
                    selectedTilePosition = new Vector2Int(x, y);
                }
            }

        _tileMap[selectedTilePosition.x, selectedTilePosition.y] = tileToSwap;
        _tileMap[tileToSwapPosition.x, tileToSwapPosition.y] = selectedTile;

        UpdateTileName(tileToSwap);
        UpdateTileName(selectedTile);
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered storing your selected tile position, instead of your selected tile instance?

Comment: That seems like a better solution but it'd still require me to loop through the matrix when I click on the tile. Maybe if I stored it's location based on it's "physical location" in the scene than that would mean I don't have to go through the matrix but that would be a very unstable solution. Do you have any hints on how could I do this better?

Comment: Why would you have to loop through? You know the location that was clicked, and can calculate coordinates from that. With the coordinates, you can directly look up `matrix[selected.x, selected.y]` with no iteration.

Comment: Where would I get selected.x and selected.y from? As selected stores an object and unless the object stores it's own position I can't see a way to get that data any other way. Is there?

Comment: "Have you considered storing your selected tile position, instead of your selected tile instance?" ie. You do not store an object, you store coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One optimization pops into my head. Don't use 2D arrays. You can do JUST fine on 1D array, also you can remove one for loop from it, in the long run improve cache hit ratio, making your code possibly faster. What I mean is this:

```
public void SwapSelected(Tile tileToSwap, uint Width)
{
    Vector3 tempPos = selectedTile.transform.position;
    selectedTile.transform.position = tileToSwap.transform.position;
    tileToSwap.transform.position = tempPos;

    uint tileToSwapPosition = UINT_MAX;
    uint selectedTilePosition = UINT_MAX;

    for (uint index = 0; index < _tileMap.length; ++index)
    {
        if (_tileMap[index] == tileToSwap)
        {
            tileToSwapPosition = index;
        }
        if (_tileMap[index] == selectedTile)
        {
            selectedTilePosition = index;
        }
    }

    _tileMap[selectedTilePosition] = tileToSwap;
    _tileMap[tileToSwapPosition] = selectedTile;

    UpdateTileName(tileToSwap);
    UpdateTileName(selectedTile);
}
```

Of course, if this runs fine, which I hope it does, you should not care that much about optimizing the code. Of course, optimal and fast-running code is ESSENTIAL, but not in spite of progress. So don't bog down on this too much, develop great games, and when this becomes a bottleneck then optimize, optimize, optimize :) Have fun man!

EDIT: As per curiosity @DMGregory started in me I ran a benchmark, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays/597790#597790

Here are the results:

```
citrus at spaceship in ~/Desktop/Projects/csharpbenchmark
$ mono Main.exe 
Jagged:   8.721   7.068   6.361   7.106   7.827   7.821   8.969   7.148   7.427  11.016 
Multidimensional:  10.204  12.013   8.750   8.861   9.101   9.978   9.439   8.442   8.843   8.873 
Singledimensional:   6.670   4.661   4.326   4.369   4.602   6.469   4.678   4.684   4.451   4.473 

citrus at spaceship in ~/Desktop/Projects/csharpbenchmark
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (tarball Tue Feb  4 20:29:35 GMT 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notification:  kqueue
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
Interpreter:   yes
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
Suspend:       hybrid
GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

I did not try this with Unity's mono implementation, as I am pretty sure it differs a touch. But vanilla mono shows, that the single dimensional arrays are faster a bit.

Comment: Note that 2D arrays in C# are contiguous, not jagged arrays like in Java, so the cache access pattern of traversing a 2D array (in the correct order) is the same as the 1D version. Your modified code is still using 2D indexing.

Comment: in C# yes, but also in Mono? Also yes, it is using  2D indexing, but I guess they could rewrite the latter lines in the form of what is in the for loop actually.

Comment: also if you think this is a wrong answer, I can take it down

Comment: If you have evidence that this is more efficient than the alternative in Mono, I'd be interested in seeing it. But at present I don't see a reason to expect this would be a substantial improvement. Since the array contains Unity objects, you're still dealing with cache misses when you call the overridden `==` operator.

Comment: well, not really a spot on answer, and I did not try it out at all, but for the time being here is a stackoverflow link. It is dotnet core, that was the closest one I could find. If you can wait, I can most probably put together some benchmark after I finish at work but until then, here you go

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45410114/2117150

Comment: This is not measuring the use case in your answer.